# ADC not working with ESP32S3

Tags: adc, esp32

I am using the MAX1039 to read a signal and read it with an ESP32S3.

> 2.7V to 3.6V, Low-Power, 4-/12-Channel, 2-Wire Serial 8-Bit ADCs

The problem is that I am not receiving any signal, I have tried:

Basically, I connected it to the i2C port:

- I scanned all the IDs available on the i2C and none responded.
- I inverted the I2C pins and nothing.
- I kept messing with the frequency I tried 10k 30k 50k 100k 200k and 300k.
- I replaced the chip.
- The voltage is 3.33V and I am using a pull-up resistor of 10k

[image]
[image]

Comment: Marckaraujo - Hi, (a) Please edit the question & add your schematic. (b) Please explain the scope traces - they look like SCL & SDA of an I2C bus, but please confirm. If they are an I2C bus, can you capture & display them both at the same time (it's a 2 channel scope), as that makes it easier to interpret. (c) What do you mean that you scanned all the IDs? How? (d) It would help if you expanded the scales on the scope (from 2V/div to 1V/div & 20us/div to 10us/div) but the waveform shape looks at least OK. You haven't shown any code. That seems to imply you believe the problem is hardware. Why?

Comment: I'm struggling to see a valid IIC address in your pictures. Please explain the meaning and value of the displayed waveforms.

Comment: @marckaraujo -  this would be easier to delve into if you posted at least a connection diagram (circuit diagram would be better), and a minimal compilable code snippet that you expect to work.

Comment: what pins of the ESP32S3 are you using? I found several incorrect pinout diagrams online, and it took my a long time to figure out. turns out 35 is scl and 33 is sda...

Comment: @SamGibson Made me realize that the problem could be the software. SDA and SCL were inverted in the code. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Marckaraujo - Hi, Regarding your comment: "*SDA and SCL were inverted in the code. Thanks for that.*" So was that the only problem, you've fixed it and your overall problem is solved? If you've now fixed this, then you could either delete the question (as it currently has no answer) or you could post a [self-answer](/help/self-answer) (and áccept it (no earlier that 2023-12-15 @ 13.39 UTC) if a better answer isn't posted by someone else before that, to effectively close the question). A self-answer should show the code fix, please, to help future readers. Thanks.